# Set state to result of database query

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

So I have a function like this to get everything from a database:

```
  retrieve() {
    db.transaction(
      tx => {
       tx.executeSql('select * from my_table', [], (trans, result) => {
        });
      }    
    );
  }
```

Now I want to set the `state` of my component to `result`, but I'm not sure how to achieve this. I've tried adding the following at various points in the `retrieve()` function but I am unable to achieve any success.

```
this.setState({
  cardholders: result
});
```

Comment: By any chance the database transaction running asynchronously? If that's the case you have to chain the in order to set the `result` as `state`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out this way:

```
db.transaction(
  tx => {
   tx.executeSql('select * from MyScannedCards', [], (trans, result) => {
    var len = result.rows.length;
    for (i=0;i<len;i++){
      cardDetails = result.rows._array[i];
      this.setState({ cardholders: this.state.cardholders.concat(cardDetails) })
    }
    });
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```js
  retrieve() {
    db.transaction(
      tx => {
       tx.executeSql('select * from my_table', [],  (trans, result) => {
        this.setState({
          cardholders: result
        });
        });
      }    
    );
  }
```